# VBA to insert an empty column with absolute reference after each column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set with many columns that contain labels in the headings and set of values of different lengths. I would like insert the labels that correspond to the each value range into subsequent new column.

My input data set:

```
A     B      C 
cat  dog    fox
red  black yellow  .......
red  white yellow  .......
grey black yellow  .......
..........................................
```

My output must look like this:

```
A    B      C     D      E     F   .......
red  cat  black  dog   yellow fox  .......
red  cat  white  dog   yellow fox  .......
grey cat  black  dog   yellow fox  .......
..........................................
```

In the first step, I used macro to insert blank columns after each column:

```
Public Sub Insert_Blank_Column()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim iCol As Long

For Each wks In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    With wks
        For iCol _
        = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).column To 1 Step -1
        .Columns(iCol).Insert
        Next iCol
    End With

Next wks

End Sub
```

However, I am not sure how to make "relative" absolute reference for each new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub Insert_Columns()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim iCol As Long

    For Each wks In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

        With wks

            For iCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 1 Step -1

                'Add a column to the right of each column.
                .Cells(1, iCol + 1).EntireColumn.Insert

                'Fill the new column with the value from the first row of the column to its left.
                Range(.Cells(2, iCol + 1), .Cells(.Cells(1, iCol).End(xlDown).Row, iCol + 1)) = .Cells(1, iCol)

            Next iCol

            'Delete the first row.
            .Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete

        End With

    Next wks

End Sub
```